# Python com between python and excel

Tags: python, excel, com

I'm trying to learn some python and I wanted for python to interact with excel using the win32 module. I found a basic example online on wiki [here](http://www.pha.com.au/kb/index.php/Python_COM_Examples).

It won't work however. 
This is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Greg/Desktop/python programming/excel2.py", line 8, in <module>
    sheet.Range("A2").Value = str(Application.SIFilter(None, c.siObjectFilter))
NameError: name 'Application' is not defined
```

My question is what does that line DO EXACTLY and why am I getting an error?

**sheet.Range("A2").Value = str(Application.SIFilter(None, c.siObjectFilter))**

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as c

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
book = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello World!"
sheet.Range("A2").Value = str(Application.SIFilter(None, c.siObjectFilter))
book.SaveAs("c:\simple_example.xls")

sheet = None
book = None
excel.Quit()
excel = None
```

Thanks sorry if I'm super noob....

Comment: Are you running it from the command line or from inside Softimage? The `Application` object only exists when you do the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you linked to looks like it's pulled straight off of [this blog](http://www.softimageblog.com/archives/11). From the sound of it, you're not trying to integrate with [Softimage](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=13571168&siteID=123112). You'll want to just take that line out.

Also, if you're working with Excel 2007 or later, you want to write to an `xlsx` file, because that's what `Excel.Application` is going to create for you.

Here's the same sample code modified with these changes.

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
book = excel.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello World!"
book.SaveAs("c:\simple_example.xlsx") # or .xls depending on version

sheet = None
book = None
excel.Quit()
excel = None
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line :

```
sheet.Range("A2").Value = str(Application.SIFilter(None, c.siObjectFilter))
```

you are trying to to turn `Application.SIFilter(None, c.siObjectFilter)` in to a string. You did not define the object called `Application`. I did not run the code, but I think it might work if you write `excel.SIFilter(None, c.siObjectFilter)`. If you are just trying to learn, write something else, and you will get an excel  file.