# Python - Convert tables from .doc / .docx-files to .xls

Tags: python, xls, docx, pywin32, xlwt

I'm tasked to convert a series of tables from `.doc` and `.docx-files` to `.xls`,

But have not managed to find an efficient way to do this. The tables may be in between other text.

I have looked into `pywin32, xlwt` and a couple of other libraries, but it seems like I have to go through a lot of steps.

Any tips for this table conversion from `*.doc/*.docx` to `*.xls` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have too many documents for copy/paste, and seek a pragmatic solution for internal use. This solution:

- Opens the file in Word in batch mode
- You could write a little script to cut everything outside  tags from the HTML
- Saves the file in HTML, but using a .xls extension
- The HTML file will open in Excel by default and you just click away the warning.

Create a macro in Word such as this:

```
Sub BatchSaveAs()
    ' Set output_dir appropriately
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "output_dir"

    outDocName = Left(ActiveDocument.Name, Len(ActiveDocument.Name) - 4) & ".xls"

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=outDocName, FileFormat:= _
        wdFormatFilteredHTML, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
        :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
        :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
        SaveAsAOCELetter:=False

    ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView

    Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Now you can run Word in batch mode through a script which calls it for each input file:

```
winword file_name /mBatchSaveAs
```

(You may need to use full path names)

If the warning on opening the HTML / Excel files is not OK, you could write a little Python script to run Excel in batch mode. This shows how to run Excel in from Python:

[Python com between python and excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164621/python-com-between-python-and-excel)

Some tricks I found useful: use finally for your clean-up; the code you need looks like VBA code, and if you're not good at VBA, record a macro to do what you want and modify for Python syntax.