# Extracting tables from a word doc

Tags: python, vba, ms-word, extract

Is there any tool to extract all tables from a word documents and converting them to a csv file or any excel extension file using python or vba

note that the word file contains both text and tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python -docx to extract table from word docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618718/python-docx-to-extract-table-from-word-docx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write tables from Word (.docx) to Excel (.xlsx) using xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043218/write-tables-from-word-docx-to-excel-xlsx-using-xlsxwriter)

Comment: [Python - Convert tables from .doc / .docx-files to .xls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591195/6045800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas` with [`python-docx`](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/). Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58336070/11380795) answer you can extract all tables from a document and put them in a list:

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd
document = Document('test.docx')

tables = []
for table in document.tables:
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            if cell.text:
                df[i][j] = cell.text
    tables.append(pd.DataFrame(df))
```

You can then save the tables to csv files by looping through the list:

```
for nr, i in enumerate(tables):
    i.to_csv("table_" + str(nr) + ".csv")
```